# Cannot create DNS zone in web console

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

When clicking on "Create Zone" in the web console under Networking/DNS, it fails with the error, "The 'parameters.managedZone' resource named '~new' does not exist." I realize there are other ways to create a zone, but has anyone had success doing it with the web console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have this error?

I've been using both the console and gcloud quite a bit lately and not seen this. i.e.: Yes, success using the web console.

Cheers,